# I cannot make a component highlighted on mouse hover in CSS

Tags: css

I want to make an highlight on mouse hover onto my div. But when I place it in span and try to highlight the spans, it cripple my layout.

I want to make a side menu that will bring a panel with link choices. I can make the Javascript no problem, but the CSS is a big problem.

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eruqdfz3/) with my code in it.

Any idea?

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-nav">
  <div class="nav link" value="clientLink">CLIENT</div>
  <div class="nav divider"></div>
  <div class="nav link" value="jobLink">JOB</div>
  <div class="nav divider"></div>
  <div class="nav link" value="employeeLink">MY SPACE</div>
  <span class="stretcher"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#main-nav {
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  top: 0%;
  left: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  background: rgb(0, 98, 184);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0, 98, 184), lightgray);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0, 98, 184), lightgray);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0, 98, 184), lightgray);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(top, rgb(0, 98, 184), lightgray);
  /* Standard syntax */
  z-index: 100;
}

.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.stretcher {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.divider {
  background-color: white;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 50px white;
}

.menuContent {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 99;
}

.nav:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  background: rgb(0, 98, 210);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, royalblue, lightgray);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, royalblue, lightgray);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, royalblue, lightgray);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(top, royalblue, lightgray);
  /* Standard syntax */
}
```

**EDIT**
Sorry as my question was not clear enough. I want to make the whole span highlighted not only the text contained in the div. Right now only the text highlighted.

Comment: Your hover states on the '.nav' elements appear to be working in the JSFiddle.  Based on what you have typed I thought the hover states were supposed to be the issue.  Can you please elaborate as to which part of the code isn't working and what exactly it is supposed to do?

Comment: @DawnPatrol i updated it, thanks for feed back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is occurring because of your dividers. You can get the same effect from setting each link to a third of the total width.

```
.nav.link{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also, remove the `margin-right:10%` from .nav and remove the stretcher and dividers completely:

```
<div id="main-nav">
  <div class="nav link" value="clientLink">CLIENT</div>
  <div class="nav link" value="jobLink">JOB</div>
  <div class="nav link" value="employeeLink">MY SPACE</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4j451fys/

Comment: I tried your update(which are not in the link you have provided). It work, but i want to keep hte divider look and make the div follow the rest of the style. The rest worked though